# Why does my website keep showing old index.html, style.css, app.js...?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem that I can't solve. I'm new to web-developing, and I coded my first web-site, bought a domain and hosting, and added my files to the public.html folder.

Whenever I change the code, either in css or js and delete the previous files in the public.html folder and then add new ones under the same name with which the code was changed, when I load the site, either by phone or desktop the site looks and all elements remain the same that I haven't changed the code at all, if I change the names of the html, css and js files, I link them and insert them that way, it only shows me a list of files in the public.html folder. The only time the code update works is when I open the site in incognito mode for browsers.

My assumption is that there are some problems with cookies and cached data, but even when I delete them in browser, the code is not updated but the site uses old files.

Does anyone know some solution to my problem, otherwise I use domain and hosting from hostinger and I haven't changed any settings in domen and hosting since I bought it.

Thank you all.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], as well as looking at [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question is more about hosting and server setup than it is about programming and therefore is off topic on Stack Overflow. You should read the help centers of sites like [webmasters.se], [sf], and others in the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-name) network to see if your question might be more on topic there.

Comment: If its working in incognito mode, there’s something in your browser that’s causing these assets to be cached. What `Cache-Control` headers are you sending from your server? What exactly are you doing to clear your cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a caching issue only, you can try implementing https://sebhastian.com/javascript-versioning/

Comment: Thanks a lot, its works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Probably your browser reads from it's cache. Either try disabling browser cache from your browser settings or open your project on your browsers "hidden-private" mode since this mode doesn't do caching.

Also there're some http headers that tells the user to do browser caching or not which you can simply set true or false as I recall. Try googleing this, thus just before returning your page set this header to your response so any other user will be able to see the changes you made, on normal browser mode since it doesn't do caching anymore.

Comment: thanks for your answer, even when i disable cookies in my browser it is showing old files, i try it on sever different browsers and devices and still have the same problem and and i realized it wasn't a problem in browser, but in the site itself.

I will google about that http headers and try some solution.

Comment: @LazarPanović cookies are related to authentication information, so disabling it won't affect caching.